# asp.net url rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to create a URL Rewriter with my own create module with use of

- web.config
- global.asax

and other files.

I don't want to rewrite URLs for only a few pages, I would like some general code for all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here somes infos:

- [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)
- [IIS URL Rewriting and ASP.NET Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/)
- [Open Source URL Rewriter for .NET / IIS / ASP.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/)
- [And here an excellent tutorial for your own module!](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://nico-pyright.developpez.com/tutoriel/asp.net/csharp/urlrewriting/)

And here is the best for me: [URL rewrite with asp.net 4.0 and IIS7](http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/URL-rewrite-with-aspnet-40-and-IIS7.aspx)